# get columns other than primary key from CHANGETABLE function sql-server

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I have two table (`InvoiceRequests`, `InvoiceRequestsLineItems`), `InvoiceRequestsLineItems` has `InvoiceRequestId` as forign key, `Qauntity` and `Rate` columns.

My both tables has change tracking enabled.

I'm writing a query that returns the Only the InvoiceRequests that has been changed with there respective Amount(calculated from `Qauntity` and `Rate` columns of `InvoiceRequestsLineItems`).

the scenario is when I update/insert into LineItems I `Join` the `LineItems` table and `ChangeTable` to get the InvoiceRequestId. So I shows customers that 'InvoiceRequest' Amount changed.

But when I delete any LineItems I lost the `InvoiceRequestId`(foreign key) from that row. Then I cant able to tell the amount has been changed for perticular InvoiceRequests.

Is there any way that `ChangeTable` function can return other columns(InvoiceRequestId) apart from PrimaryKey(InvoiceRequestLineItemId).

Solution like adding trigger and keep the deleted record in separate table will increase lot of overhead.

Please provide any suggestion, that I can do with minimal changes. Thanks

```
SELECT 
      CTIRL.INVOICEREQUESTSID [InvoiceRequestId], 
      IR.STATUS [Status],
      ERIL.[InvoiceRequestAmount], 
      CAST(0 as BIT) [Deleted]
    FROM 
    (SELECT [IRS].INVOICEREQUESTSID, CTL.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, CTL.sys_change_operation 
        FROM INVOICEREQUESTLINEITEMS [IRS] 
        JOIN CHANGETABLE( CHANGES dbo.INVOICEREQUESTLINEITEMS, @ctversion) CTL
        ON CTL.INVOICEREQUESTLINEITEMSID = [IRS].INVOICEREQUESTLINEITEMSID
    ) AS CTIRL    
    LEFT JOIN dbo.INVOICEREQUESTS IR 
    ON CTIRL.INVOICEREQUESTSID = IR.INVOICEREQUESTSID 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            IRLI.INVOICEREQUESTSID, 
            SUM(
            IRLI.QUANTITY * IRLI.RATE + COALESCE(IRLI.TAXAMOUNT, 0)
            ) [InvoiceRequestAmount] 
        FROM 
            INVOICEREQUESTLINEITEMS IRLI 
        GROUP BY 
            IRLI.INVOICEREQUESTSID
        ) AS ERIL
    ON ERIL.INVOICEREQUESTSID = RES.InvoiceRequestId 
    WHERE 
      (
        CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK(5, CTIRL.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) = 1 
        OR CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK(7, CTIRL.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) = 1  
        OR CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK(11, CTIRL.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS) = 1        
        OR CTIRL.sys_change_operation = 'D' 
        OR CTIRL.sys_change_operation = 'I'
      )
```

Comment: You could create a trigger on delete to copy what you need to an "old lines" tables

Comment: Thanks @Kendle, Is it the only solution? Actually it will add the overhead, I'll keep this solution at last.